# ETL with PLSQL procedures - How to combine two similar schemas?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, etl

So consider two similar database schemas A and B

A has entries like

```
Table_Employee
NAME, PHONE_NUMBER, etc.
```

and

B has similar tables like

```
Table_Worker:
NAME, PHONE, etc.
```

There are still minor differences though, such as different formats of phone numbers or maybe other data that is missing in one schema but could be generated from entries that already exist.

Now I would like to combine the entries of both schemas and create a new one (C for example). Basically, I would like to find out how to do this with PLSQL procedures, just combining both schemas, while invoking minimal transformations on certain entries so that everything is homogeneous again and all entries of schema A and B exist in C.

I could also transform the data on the spot and then merge everything together or use two extra schemas but I don't think that is how it's done in practice and my minimal PLSQL knowledge is not helping.

So how could I do this kind of data mapping in PLSQL?

Comment: This will be accomplished with a couple of insert statements.  That is all that can be said with a general answer.  The complexity is in how to deal with specific transformations, and how to deduplicate if that is necessary.

Comment: I'm not clear what the multiple schemas have to do with the technical requirement, other than complicating deployment. Is this just about merging two sets of data into a third table?

Comment: Maybe you can use union after transforming each field's datatype according to the other view's/schema's datatype into a view.

Comment: A simple union will do the trick. And as suggested create a simple view and use it. Since it to be up to date so creating a table or materialised view with need a refresh method. So simple view will suffice the need.